# bar function output property 'children' in MatLab before 2014

Tags: matlab

I am using `MatLab R2015a`, and the software tool I got is developed in `R2008a`. The tool has all `.m` files.

```
handles.bars = bar( 1:length(indxSubTypeSorted), processes(indxSubTypeSorted, i), 'FaceColor', colors(j, :), 'EdgeColor', edgeColor, 'BarWidth', 0.4);
```

The output for this line on R2015a has empty property for 'children'

> > get(handles.bars(1),'children')

ans =

```
0x0 empty GraphicsPlaceholder array.
```

But the software tool developed in R2008a is using the value of this property.

Could anyone please tell me what the value would be if I run this on R2008a, and how to find the correct value from R2015a?

Comment: What is the software tool doing with with the children of the bar graph? You are not providing much useful information...

Answer (score 0):

To customize the graph, use properties of the actual object. As specified here, things changed with and after R2014b http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graphics_transition/why-is-the-children-property-empty-for-some-objects.html 
You will no more find number identifiers. Therefore, for both Matlab versions:

```
handles.bars = bar( 1:10, rand(10), 'FaceColor', [rand, rand, rand], 'EdgeColor', [rand, rand, rand], 'BarWidth', 0.4);
```

Then it depends on what your code does afterward. Say you want to change `FaceColor`, in Matlab R2008:

```
gc = get(handles.bars(1),'children')
set(gc,'FaceColor',[rand rand rand]);
```

Whereas in Matlab R2014b:

```
handles.bars(1).FaceColor = [rand rand rand];
```

Comment: Please look at answer part. The post is too long to be posted from here.
The link you gave me does not tell me how to find values for children.

Comment: I modified my answer. However, it also depends what the code did after getting the handles of the children.